# Angular Unit Test - nested async pipes

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, angular-unit-test, jasmine-marbles

Consider the following code:

```
app.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}


app.component.html

<div *ngIf="userService.isUserLoggedIn$ | async">
 <span class="username">{{(userService.user$ | async)?.name}}</span>
</div>
```

This is a simplification for one of my components.
I tried to write a basic unit test:

```
  it('should display the username', () => {
    userService.isUserLoggedIn$ = cold('-a|', {a: true});
    userService.user$ = cold('-a|', {a: {name: 'foo'});

    fixture.detectChanges();
    getTestScheduler().flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();


    const el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.username')).nativeElement as HTMLSpanElement;
    expect(el.innerText.trim()).toBe('foo);
  });
```

I'm using the jasmine marbles library.

The problem is that the span doesn't have the correct value, it's always empty.
I guess is because of the 2 nested async pipes. After the observables are flushed, the ngIf condition becomes true, the span is created and a new subscription for the **user$** is created. But because the observable completed, the span will be empty.

I'm not sure if this is the correct explanation...

My question is how should I test this kind of scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Defining `userService.isUserLoggedIn$ = cold('-a|', {a: true});` and `userService.user$ = cold('-a|', {a: {name: 'foo'});` after `TestBed.configureTestingModule` is too late. These values have already been injected and `isUserLoggedIn$` and `user$` are values that are "static". Setting them at a later point in time doesn't tell the observable sequence to update this (no emissions happen).

When you mock `userService`, attach the `isUserLoggedIn$` and `user$` before the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.